# How to compare the headers of the df with other df headers using Fuzzy Matching in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created 3 dataframes by  executing following code. 
sample.csv

```
id|code|name|Lname|mname
2|AA|BB|CC|DD|
```

sample1.csv

```
id|code|name|Lname|mname
1|A|B|C|D|
```

sample2.csv

```
id1|code1|name1|Lnam|mnam
3|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD|
```

I have compare the headers of the data frames using fuzzy logic if all header columns  2 files (sample1,sample2) average matching is 85% then i have to print both files are same.

```
example :
  sample1.csv vs sample2.csv  

+---------+--------+-----+
|f1_lab   |  f2_lab|score|
+---------+--------+-----+
| id      |   id1  |  80 |
| code    |  code1 |  89 |
| name    |   name1|  89 |
| Lname   |   Lnam |  89 |
| mname   |   mnam |  89 | 
+---------+--------+-----+
```

my final output will be average of scores ex: `80+89+89+89+89/5=87.2` (avgage score)  .

if average scores are above 80  the I have to print output like `sample1 and sample2 matched ,`.

like that i have to compare all file header with other file header. I need to identify all matched files.

can please help me on this.

please find below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ALS").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='True', inferschema='false').option("delimiter", "|").load('C:/Users/test/Desktop/sample1.csv')
df1 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='True', inferschema='false').option("delimiter", "|").load('C:/Users/test/Desktop/sample2.csv')
df2 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='True', inferschema='false').option("delimiter", "|").load('C:/Users/test/Desktop/sample3.csv')
lab= [col_name for col_name in df.columns]
lab1=[col_name1 for col_name1 in df1.columns]
lab2=[col_name1 for col_name1 in df2.columns]
lab1head=sc.parallelize(lab).zipWithIndex()
a = spark.createDataFrame(lab1head,['label1', "Index"])
lab1head=sc.parallelize(lab1).zipWithIndex()
a1 = spark.createDataFrame(lab1head,['label2', "Index"])
lab2head=sc.parallelize(lab1).zipWithIndex()
a1 = spark.createDataFrame(lab2head,['label3', "Index"])

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
def match_name(name, list_names, min_score=0):
    max_score = -1
    # Returning empty name for no match as well
    max_name = ""
    # Iternating over all names in the other
    for name2 in list_names:
        #Finding fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.ratio(name, name2)
        # Checking if we are above our threshold and have a better score
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = name2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)

dict_list = []
for name in a.label1:
    # Use our method to find best match, we can set a threshold here
    match = match_name(name, a1.label2, 75)
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update({"labhead" : name})
    dict_.update({"labhead1" : match[0]})
    dict_.update({"score" : match[1]})
    dict_list.append(dict_)
```

Comment: Are you talking about fuzzy string matching instead of fuzzy logic?

Comment: yes Nihal  fuzzy string matching

Comment: ya i have tried to use but i am getting error like " Column is not iterable"

Comment: from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
def match_name(name, list_names, min_score=0):
    max_score = -1
    # Returning empty name for no match as well
    max_name = ""
    # Iternating over all names in the other
    for name2 in list_names:
        #Finding fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.ratio(name, name2)
        # Checking if we are above our threshold and have a better score
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = name2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)

Comment: i have used above code

Comment: Add your full code in the question.

Comment: added the full code